# Web clipper for Ipad

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, notes.app, evernote

While browsing on my Ipad2 we'd like to take notes and save whole websites (not just bookmark them). The Evernote add-on on Chrome (on my PC) gives the exact functionality that I'm looking for. Is there an equivalent app for Ipad? Note that for a special accessibility reason we use Chrome instead of Safari. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered a reasonable way to add the Evernote bookmarklet to Chrome on my iPad.

1. Start to create a new bookmark on any page by clicking the star in the URL bar
2. Enter a name for the bookmarklet. I just used Evernote.
3. Delete the URL in the bookmark dialog box and replace with the Evernote bookmarklet:

   ```
   javascript:(function(){EN_CLIP_HOST='http://www.evernote.com';try{var%20x=document.createElement('SCRIPT');x.type='text/javascript';x.src=EN_CLIP_HOST+'/public/bookmarkClipper.js?'+(new%20Date().getTime()/100000);document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(x);}catch(e){location.href=EN_CLIP_HOST+'/clip.action?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title);}})();
   ```
4. Save the bookmark

Now if you type the name of the bookmark Chrome should show an autocomplete list with the Javascript code — just select it and press Return. For me there is a longish pause before the Evernote pop up appears.